# AliasToBean DTO with known type

Tags: nhibernate

All the examples I am finding for using the AliasToBean transformer use the sessions CreateSqlQuery method rather than the CreateQuery method. They also only return the basic value types, and not any object's of the existing mapped types.

I was hoping it would be possible that my DTO have a property of one of my mapped Domain objects, like below, but I am not getting traction. I get the following exception:

> Could not find a setter for property '0' in class 'namespace.DtoClass'

My select looks like the following on my mapped classes (I have confirmed the mappings pull correctly):

```
SELECT 
fcs.MeasurementPoint, 
fcs.Form, 
fcs.MeasurementPoint.IsUnscheduled as ""IsVisitUnscheduled"", 
fcs.MultipleEntryAllowed
FROM FormCollectionSchedule fcs
```

My end query will be more complex, but I wanted to confirm if this AliasToBean method can return mapped domain objects as well as basic field values from tables retrieved via sql.

the query execution looks like the following:

```
var result = session.CreateQuery(hqlQuery.ToString())
                .SetResultTransformer(NHibernate.Transform.Transformers.AliasToBean(typeof (VisitFormCollectionResult)))
                .List<VisitFormCollectionResult>();
```

note: the VisitFormCollectionResult DTO has more properties, but I wanted to know if I could populate the domain object properties matching the names

**update** found my problem! I have to explicitly alias each of the fields. once I added an alias, even though the member property on the class matched my DTO's property name, the hydration of the object worked correctly.

Comment: Could you post some code? DTO, Nhibernate Query, etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to my own question was that each of the individual fields in the select needed an explicit alias matching the property, regardless if the field name already matched the property name of the DTO object:

```
SELECT 
fcs.MeasurementPoint as "MeasurementPoint", 
fcs.Form as "Form", 
fcs.MeasurementPoint.IsUnscheduled as "IsVisitUnscheduled", 
fcs.MultipleEntryAllowed as "MultipleEntryAllowed"
FROM FormCollectionSchedule fcs
```